# I cannot update from Android Studio (AS) 3.2.1 to 3.4. "Downloading patch" just quits just before end of progress bar

Tags: android-studio

The title says it all. Are there known problems with updating?

Here's a screenshot of just before I'm thrown back to "Welcome to AS 3.2.1":

[image]

And here's where I'm thrown back to:

[image]

Needless to say, I tried updating by using `Configure, Check for updates`. SEVERAL times. Same thing every time, I assume. After the previous did not update or leave any message, I watched and hit print screen over and over to get a shot of just where the failure occurred. No message.

Same thing happened when I had a project open and tried to update when prompted.

But now, when I open a project I AM NOT prompted to update. When I click `Help, Check for updates`, I get this screen and I click `Update and restart` but the same termination occurs after several minutes.

[image]

Nothing from today is in my downloads folder. Is there somewhere else to look? (I don't see how that's relevant since downloading the patch aborted before finishing.)

Is anyone having similar problems? What have you done to update?

I don't want to uninstall 3.2.1 and do fresh install of 3.4. Does updating work or not?

If not, what else can I do but start from scratch with new 3.4.

Comment: Please don't abuse the tag creation privilege and create tags like the ones you did in revision 1 - these add no value to any posts, and are likely to get burninated if they somehow survive peer checks after being created.

Comment: I apologize. And I thank you. I don't need no steenking -1s staring at me! But I didn't know how to draw attention to failed update. Just saying "Android-studio" doesn't discriminate much. I guess since you took out the two tags I made up and didn't add any, you don't have any suggestions about what other tag(s) to use. Or what to do.